# How to pronounce the symbols $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $\mathfrak{m}_K$?

Tags: number-theory, notation, algebraic-number-theory, pronunciation

The context is algebraic number theory.

How to pronounce the symbols $\mathcal{O}_K$ (ring of integers in $K$) and $\mathfrak{m}_K$ (maximal ideal) ?

How to pronounce $\mathcal{O}_K^n$ ?

Note `\mathcal{O}_K` for $\mathcal{O}_K$ and `\mathfrak{m}_K` for $\mathfrak{m}_K$.

There is [book](https://02522-cua.github.io/lecturenotes/pdf/Chang_1983_Handbook%20for%20Spoken%20Mathematics.pdf) has some clue.

So I am thinking the following pronunciations:

$\mathcal{O}_K \xrightarrow{pronunciation} O~\text{subscript}~K$

$\mathcal{O}_K^n \xrightarrow{pronunciation} O~\text{subscript}~K~\text{to the}~n~\text{power},~~\text{Or,}~O~\text{subscript}~K~\text{raised to the}~n$

$\mathfrak{m}_K \xrightarrow{pronunciation} m~\text{subscript}~K$.

Is it enough ?

Comment: I would just say oh-sub-kay, oh-sub-kay-to-the-en, em-sub-kay.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thanks. So use `sub` instead of `subscript`

Comment: Nothing wrong with "subscript", I'm just telling you what I would say, not that other options are wrong.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I understand 'to save energy'

Comment: I call these 'Oh Kay en,' don't feel the need to include the details of "sub" and such. Also in algebraic geometry, this is the structure sheaf, and I'm pretty sure that this notation is not an accident. In a suitably general setting, you could probably just call it "the structure sheaf."

Comment: If the $n$ in $K^n$ is not an exponent, say "kay sup n". Now does anyone know how to pronounce $\sinh x$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, thanks. May be $sinh~x$ should enhance the hyperbolic property of $sin~x$ here. Say, `sin hyperbolic x` or `hyperbolic sin x`. What do we pronounce for $h_H$ ? Is the pronunciation `h sub capital H`  alright ?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176070/26369 for hyperbolic trig pronunciations

Comment: MAI, to save energy is one thing, but for several people it helped to know that $\mathcal{O}$ is not "Oh" but rather "calligraphic Oh". Of course you would skip this afterwards then. Actually, see [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2922/who-first-introduced-the-notation-mathcalo-in-algebraic-geometry-or-algebra/2924?noredirect=1) for the notion.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, so you suggest to pronounce `calligraphic Oh` for $\mathcal{O}$. Is it ? Actually I read some slide in a conference

Comment: @DietrichBurde, how to pronounce $\mathcal{C}$ for any cap letter ? Here `\mathcal{C}` for $\mathcal{C}$. Should I say `script C` or `caligraphic C` ?